# how to observe the iOS mapView didChangeVisibleRegion

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit

hello Im working on an app that will show annotations over where the user is currently zoomed into, however I don't know how to use one of the functions because I am fairly new to mapkit.

```
    func mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
         if mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta = ?
    }
```

Im using firebase and don't want to pull out every annotation that has ever been entered but only pull out annotations when a user is at a certain zoom and show those annotations. which is where I'm at a blank, the question mark is where I don't know what to enter. If anyone knows please help!? thank you!

Comment: You write a class that implements `MKMapViewDelegate`. That class could be your ViewController. That class contains your method. Set `mapView.delegate = yourClassThatImplementsMapViewDelegate`.

Comment: I don't know what goes on the other side of the equal sign do you have an example

Comment: Do you have a class that implements MKMapViewDelegate?

Answer (score -1):

I do not use swift, so I can't provide actual coding....  but the how the coding should work.  This can all be performed in an HTTP request thread.

func mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
/* App side */
// HTTP Method here pass the mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta and mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta

```
/* server side */
// Do math from the delta values passed
// Query the database based off the math
// Output data in json format

/* App side */
// Redraw the map annotations based of the json output
```

}